# PHP using variable value in a variable name

Tags: php, string, variables, scope

I have some variables like this:

```
$barbarian = 7;
$archer = 7;
$giant = 7;
```

And a function like this:

```
function army($troopData,$troop,$thing){

    if(isset($troop) && $troopData+1 == ${"$thing"}){
        $troopData++;
        $text = "<span class='army-icon active top-lvl $thing-icon'><span>$troopData</span></span>";
    }elseif(isset($troop)){
        $troopData++;
        $text = "<span class='army-icon active $thing-icon'><span>$troopData</span></span>";
    }else{
        $text = "<span class='army-icon $thing-icon'><span></span></span>";
    }
  return $text;

}
```

Notice the first if:
`if(isset($troop) && $troopData+1 == ${"$thing"}){`

The function is called like this:

`army($troopslvl4000000,$troops4000000, "barbarian");
army($troopslvl4000001,$troops4000001, "archer");`

The last parameter is named $thing in the function.

So I need to first line of the if to check if:

1) `$troop` is set.
2) `$troopData+1 == $barbarian` (or whatever thing is. `$archer` for the second function call)

But it isn't working. It is always using the elseif or the else. The first if never gets called...

Comment: In your first if statement, what is this `${"$thing"}` supposed to be? That doesn't look like valid PHP to me

Comment: @mituw16 that is variable variablename. if `$varname = archer` and `$archer = 5` then `$$varname = 5`

Comment: yeah, the `${"$thing"}` notation is also correct, as is `$$thing`. I think the issue is the lack of the `global` statements as in my answer.

Comment: Note that with variable variablenames you have some _magic_ behaviour.   I would try to avoid such magical stuff for readability of the code.

Comment: Interesting. In all my years doing PHP, I've never come across `${"$variable"}` syntax before. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a construct like:

```
$s1 = "somevar";
$$s1 = "test";
echo $somevar; // will output: test
```

This in your code:

```
function army($troopData,$troop,$thing){
    global $barbarian;
    global $archer;
    global $giant;

    if(isset($troop) && $troopData+1 == $$thing){
    ...
}
```

## Edit:

note that you should enable access to the `$barbarian` etc. variables inside the function!

Comment: In the EditCase you should get a warninng from php which says "$barbarian is not defined, assumed 'barbarian' " or something like this

Answer (score 0):

For readability to avoid mistakes with the priority of oporaters add brackets like

```
if(isset($troop) && ( $troopData+1 == ${"$thing"})
```

In this case as a comment said you do not have to: http://php.net/manual/fa/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: `==` has higher preceedence than `&&`, so leaving the parentheses out is safe. However, sometimes readability improves if you _do_ use the superfluous parentheses...

Comment: @MartenKoetsier changed that. Sory!